# error installing php dependencies on ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a vps with linux `ubuntu 20.04 LTS` installed, I also installed the lamp stack to upload my web projects, php with version 7.4, now I need to install some more php libraries for example: `php-gd` so run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```

but when installing I get the following error: `php7.4-cli : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18) but 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.17 is to be installed`

and actually it won't let me install anything else, because it always throws me that error.. any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try `apt install php7.4-common=7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18`.

Comment: ^^^ Indeed you may try but it won't work.

Comment: running the command i get this libapache2-mod-php7.4 : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.17) but 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18 is to be installed
 php7.4-curl : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.17) but 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18 is to be installed
 php7.4-dev : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.17) but 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18 is to be installed

Comment: And `apt install libapache2-mod-php7.4=7.4.4-4ubuntu2.18` ?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer If the repository has that version APT selects and install it without complaining. The problem is the version mismatch likely related with some problem the OP didn't mention while installing LAMP.

Comment: @ChanganAuto What should I do, am I lost?

Comment: You should perhaps review the LAMP instructions and figure out what went wrong.